# Selenium Webdriver - Clicking on Banner

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on `<` and `>` button of the banner which keeps on rotating after few seconds in amazon.in but unable to do so.

I wrote the following code but still not successful

```
driver.get("amazon.in");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Previous page')]")).click();
```

It does not click on `<` button on the banner which is displayed on the top of the page.

Comment: Did you check if the element is present in the intermittent page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the following code to click on next `>` and previous `<` arrows of slider.

```
driver.get("http://www.amazon.in/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
// Forward navigation
for(int i =0;i<3;i++)
{
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='a-carousel-goto-nextpage']")).click();
      Thread.sleep(1000);
  }

// back navigation
for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
{
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='a-carousel-goto-prevpage']")).click();
     Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to use `Thread.sleep()` not to mention you are mixing it with implicit waits.

Comment: When you are writing automation, you don't need to see the effect. If you need to detect the effect, you can either test it with code to make sure the click was successful, etc.

Comment: You have posted code that will live on SO for years using a bad practice. Others may see this code and copy/use it thinking it's OK when it's not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141381/discussion-between-narendra-rajput-and-jeffc).

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem that OP hasn't asked to solve. If you want to solve it for yourself, google `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: In the first sentence of his question?

Comment: Again, you are trying to solve problems that the OP has not asked to solve. He's just asked to click the < and > buttons... that's it. Not wait, not see the banner move.

Answer (score 0):

When I write code that I'm likely to reuse, I put it into functions. Here's a function to click the next and prev arrows on the banner.

```
public static void clickNextBanner()
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.a-carousel-goto-nextpage")).click();
}

public static void clickPrevBanner()
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.a-carousel-goto-prevpage")).click();
}
```

Comment: If you found this (or any) answer helpful, please upvote it. If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using Explicit Wait

```
WebElement previous =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Previous page')]"));
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Previous page')]"))); 
    previous.click();
```